Publish Net 8 WebApi project fails with file not found exception
I get this error publishing a net 8 Web Api project:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Metadata file 'D:\GIT\DWA\MAIN\Fuoco.Authentication.DWA\bin\x64\Release\net8.0-windows8.0\win-x64\Fuoco.Authentication.DWA.dll' could not be found  DWA.API CSC 0   

DWA.API is the Host project, Fuoco.Authentication.DWA is a class library. In fact that path doesn't exist but the output of the build is in this folder:
D:\GIT\DWA\MAIN\Fuoco.Authentication.DWA\bin\x64\Release\net8.0-windows8.0 
publish process add a win-x64 folder after net8.0-windows8.0
this the configuration for Fuoco.Authentication.DWA, and all projects in the solution
Target framework : net 8
Target OS : windows
Target OS version : 8.0
Supported OS version : 8.0
Platform target : x64
Building the whole project in release x64 works fine, but publishing doesn't.
this the publish configuration:


Do you try to delete bin folder then rebuild and republish?

yes i did, no changes
